# Issues with tables being moved to next page due to empty space

Tags: tables, floats, sectioning, page-breaking

I have an issue with my tables not wanting to fit onto the pages of my document.

As can be seen by the first page, there is plenty of room for the tables, but for some reason on page two there is a lot of white space, which forces the fourth table onto page 3

I have tried using

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]   
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}                 
    \titlespacing\section{0pt}{0pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
```

in the preamble, but with no success.

Can someone please help me solve this issue?

[image: picture of error]

This link contains my preamble
(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26008215/Main.tex)

This link contains the Latex file with the tables
(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26008215/BilagC3.tex)

p.s. I run a windows 7 PC with TexnicCenter

Comment: I suggest to use sidewaystabe instead of placing everything rotated. This is not best practice.

Answer (score 4):

Using `\begin{table}` alone is equivalent to

```
\begin{table}[tbp]
```

Change all occurrences of `\begin{table}` in `BilagC3.tex` into

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
```

[image]